# how to do properly discard similar element from the list?

Tags: python

I have list like this:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
b = [10,11,13,2,14,7]
```

I want output like this:

```
b = [10,11,13,14]
```

if an element of a is in b then it has been discarded.
please, anyone can tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

`b = [x for x in b if x not in a]`

Works like this:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
b = [10,11,13,2,14,7]
b = [x for x in b if x not in a]

print b
>> [10, 11, 13, 14]
```

Re: @DeepSpace's suggestion, looking for elements of a set in a list will go significantly faster than looking for elements of a list in another list, so declare `a` as a `set()`

```
a = set([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
b = [10,11,13,2,14,7]
b = [x for x in b if x not in a]
```

Comment: This is `O(len(a) * len(b))`. Make `a` a set and this will become `O(len(b))` as set lookup is `O(1)` rather than list lookup which is `O(n)`

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out! Added to answer.